# Gradient Layer of CollectionViewCell's subview exists only on first admission of View COntroller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, cagradientlayer

I have a `CollectionViewViewController` which is pushed from another one. This `CollectionViewViewController`'s view has two subviews: simple UIView with label inside and `UICollectionView`. When it's presented for the first time everything works totally fine, and gradient is being shown correctly. But when I pop this View Controller (so it's being deallocated) and push it again from the same parent View Controlle, the gradient isn't being shown.

The cell is dequeued like below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PageScrollGeminiCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PageScrollGeminiCell
    let item = viewModel.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.configure(withTitle: item.name, description: item. description, imageURL: item.imageUrl, gradientColor: item.color, theme: theme)
    mainView.geminiView.animateCell(cell)
    return cell
}
```

And here is what I do in cell's class method and cell life cycle:

```
private var gradientColor: UIColor?
private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer?
[...]
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    setupView()
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    return nil
}
override func layoutSubviews() {
    if gradientLayer != nil {
        gradientView.layer.sublayers = nil
    }
    if let color = gradientColor {
        let gradientPoints = (CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.15), CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0))
        self.gradientLayer = gradientView.applyGradient(with: [color, color.withAlphaComponent(0.08)], gradient: .vertical(gradientPoints))
    }
}
// MARK: Private
private func setupView() {
    clipsToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = 15
    backgroundColor = .clear
    addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
    containerView.addSubview(gradientView)
    containerView.addSubview(labelsContainerView)
    labelsContainerView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    labelsContainerView.addSubview(descriptionLabel)
    containerView.snp.makeConstraints { maker in
        maker.edges.equalToSuperview()
    }
    backgroundImageView.snp.makeConstraints { maker in
        maker.edges.equalToSuperview()
    }
    gradientView.snp.makeConstraints { maker in
        maker.leading.trailing.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }
    labelsContainerView.snp.makeConstraints { maker in
        maker.leading.top.equalTo(16)
        maker.trailing.equalTo(-16)
    }
    titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { maker in
        maker.top.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
    }
    descriptionLabel.snp.makeConstraints { maker in
        maker.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.bottom).offset(8)
        maker.leading.trailing.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }
}
// MARK: - Internal
func configure(withTitle title: String?, description: String?, imageURL: String?, gradientColor: UIColor?, theme: Themeable) {
    backgroundImageView.setImage(withString: imageURL)
    titleLabel.text = title
    titleLabel.font = theme.font.h2
    descriptionLabel.text = description
    descriptionLabel.font = theme.font.b1
    self.gradientColor = gradientColor
}
```

Also I want to show you `applyGradient` func:

```
func applyGradient(with colours: [UIColor], gradient orientation: GradientOrientation) -> CAGradientLayer {
    layoutSubviews()
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.colors = colours.map { $0.cgColor }
    gradient.startPoint = orientation.startPoint
    gradient.endPoint = orientation.endPoint
    gradient.cornerRadius = layer.cornerRadius
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    return gradient
}
```

What I discovered is that when the View Controller is being presented for the first time layoutSubviews() method is being called two times, but every next time is being called only one time per each cell.

For now I'm not quiet sure if I'm not inserting more than 1 sublayer to my cell, but I'm sure that I'm clearing sublayer array, so I think it's not the problem.

Comment: "When it's presented for the first time everything works totally fine" - what is presented exactly? and where do you pop the VC?

Comment: @VadimF. The whole question is about one view controller (`CollectionViewViewController`). I pop this by pressing back button on navigation bar.

Comment: edited the answ

Answer (score 0):

The layoutSubviews() shouldn't be called, the app calls this func by itself when needed ( thats why it's called twice at the beginning )
As stated in Swift Developer website:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews

> You should not call this method directly. If you want to force a layout update, call the setNeedsLayout() method instead to do so prior to the next drawing update. If you want to update the layout of your views immediately, call the layoutIfNeeded() method.

Try avoiding using or calling layoutSubviews(), instead you can try to set gradientLayer variable in a func and calling it whenever it needed to be called, try below setupView()

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: I'm not calling this method, I've override it.

Comment: I think you are calling it in func applyGradient(with colours: [UIColor], gradient orientation: GradientOrientation) -> CAGradientLayer {
    layoutSubviews() ... }

Comment: I'm not. It is called by app itself, after `gradient.frame = self.bounds`.